# Laravel Associative Array Illegal string offset

Tags: php, laravel

I am playing around the mailchimp api and need to access some data.

this is an array from the api, which I need to loop trough.

```
array:19 [▼
      "id" => "123123123"
      "email_address" => "sam.vines@discworld.com"
      "unique_email_id" => "c9a3123326649c8"
      "email_type" => "html"
      "status" => "subscribed"
      "merge_fields" => array:2 [▼
        "FNAME" => "Sam"
        "LNAME" => "Vines"
      ]
      "stats" => array:2 [▼
        "avg_open_rate" => 0
        "avg_click_rate" => 0
      ]
      "ip_signup" => ""
      "timestamp_signup" => ""
      "ip_opt" => "12.123.12.12"
      "timestamp_opt" => "2016-10-27T13:53:02+00:00"
      "member_rating" => 2
      "last_changed" => "2016-10-27T13:53:02+00:00"
      "language" => ""
      "vip" => false
      "email_client" => ""
      "location" => array:6 [▶]
      "list_id" => "7698082412"
      "_links" => array:8 [▶]
]
```

in my view I loop trough with:

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $key => $user)
  <ul>
    <li>{{$user[$key]}}</li>
  </ul>
@endforeach
```

This exception is thrown:

```
Illegal string offset 'id'...
```

I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Why would `$user` have an element with the same key as `$mailchimp`? Either show `$user` - which is the value already - or `$mailchimp[$key]`. Although the last is kind of pointless in a `foreach` loop unless you need to change it...

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be like this:

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $key => $user)
 <ul>
   <li>{{$user}}</li>
 </ul>
@endforeach
```

**Update**

To print the values of `$mailchimp` you can directly access them as:

```
{{ $mailchimp['email_address'] }}
{{ $mailchimp['merge_fields']['FNAME'] }} {{ $mailchimp['merge_fields']['LNAME'] }}
{{ $mailchimp['stats']['avg_open_rate'] }}
```

Comment: with {{$user}} I get this "htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: It's because in `$mailchimp` some of the values are array and Laravel's blade syntax `{{$user}}` only accepts strings.

Comment: @Mamulasa `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` this error given for inside your array list its also contains multiple array. This `foreach` acceptable for single array not for multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more like this:

```
@foreach($mailchimp as $user)
    @foreach($user as $key => $value)
      <ul>
        <li>{{value}}</li>
      </ul>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

This will give you an unordered list for each user with their values.

Comment: I also tried this before, with this exception: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()..."

Comment: just after the first line of code, try putting {{dd($user)}} and see what it outputs to your page.  It should give you all the details of what exactly is inside the $user variable, and then you can figure out why you can't ouput it as expected.